# Ajax-based authentication fails using IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, authentication, internet-explorer-9

I have Ajax-based login and signup functionality built into a Fancybox modal. User clicks login button, form inside Fancybox opens, user submits, and Ajax response reloads page with user authenticated. I'm using PHP on the server side.

The functionality works fine in all browsers except IE9. I have the same server-side authentication code, but not using Ajax, working fine in IE9 on other sites. So somehow the fact that this is Ajax-based in causing it to behave strangely in IE9.

When debugging the response output in IE9, everything is exactly as it should be and the same as on other browsers. The form is serialized and submitted, the server validates the form, authenticates the user and returns successfully back to browser. However, IE9 doesn't think so. When I by-pass the form data on the server and manually force the code to authenticate a specific user, IE9 still fails to do anything, whilst other browsers comply. If I force the code to authenticate a specific user as part of a normal page-load, it works and IE9 complies.

Just to re-iterate, this only occurs on IE9, not on other browsers. However illogical it sounds, it is as if what happens server-side has no bearing in IE9.

Is anyone aware of any IE9-specific issues that might be causing this? I have tried:

- Debugging everything line-by-line
- Running in IE9 in compatibility mode
- Disabling all other forms on the page

I'm not really sure what else I could be looking into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

After some further investigation, it appears that IE9 could not update its session because it has difficulties handling cookies with underscores in them.

In this case, the local development environment was using the host dev_v2.mysite.com. The problem did not appear on staging.mysite.com and changing local to dev2.mysite.com fixed the problem as well.